# Is it ok to have an Adsense ad in each post, showing full view?

Tags: google-adsense

I have searched online, and can't find a concrete answer, would this be breaching the Adsense rules?

I have a Wordpress site with a youtube video custom post type. When a query is run, it will display all posts in full view, which is basically a  youtube video, a few lines of text and hopefully an Adsense text ad at the bottom. I was then planning on having a couple ads on the sidebar.

The problem is i'm not sure if that is breaking the Adsense rules, because the query will show multiple posts (more than 3). However, there isn't a "page" that would have more than 3 on it. Would the query results be a "page" and subject to 3 total ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A page in this context is a URL. If you show 10 articles at yoursite.com/archive, then that is still 1 page, not 10 pages. If you have 10 adverts on that URL then that would violate Adsense T&Cs.

You can get round this in a couple of ways. The first is to put the ads only on the full blog post, and just have the video/text as the "intro". However, if you don't have more content that just the video/text that's a little pointless.

The second way is to only show ads on the first three posts. Exactly how you do that I cannot answer, but you can ask over at the [Wordpress Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks! I think I will use one of the wordpress plugins that inserts only 3 ads between the posts.... better to be safe than sorry!